# 403 Forbidden with not adding www to the domain

Tags: nginx

I am getting a 403 on our homepage when users do not add www to the domain. What would cause this? We are on a LEMP stack. 403s have mysteriously happened in the past for an hour or so and then fixed itself. Something strange is happening and I cant figure it out. Are there setting in the www.conf file that would cause this?

Comment: Check your error log.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons that could cause this. First, check your DNS records to see if www.domain.com and domain.com point to the same IP address. Then, check your nginx's configuration to see if you have a server block that has a server_name option that matches domain.com. If you don't have on, normally nginx's action is to fallback to your default server (if you do have one configured).

Comment: This is most certainly a server issue. Some Im not sure why Michael Hampton is putting this on hold as off-topic. The question is pretty clear.

Comment: Anyway, The nginx.conf has the domain listed with and without the www. There are A Records with and without the www pointing to the same IP address. Something within our LEMP stack has to be causing this. The error states 403 Forbidden nginx.

Comment: What does your nginx logfile says?

Comment: nginx log is giving me a cannot connect to host issue, which is a whole different problem. I see nothing regarding 403 errors. Though, I am have not checked the other VM which I am about to do...

Comment: nothing regarding this can be found in the logs. Im looking at the error and access logs. I do get a error in finding php5-fpm-www-2.socks errors along with a lot of pages that have not been served saying no such file or directory, yet I can access those pages myself.

Comment: Try running these three commands through a shell, where $path_to_www is the complete path where you're storing your PHP, HTML, CSS, JS, etc. files:

    sudo find $path_to_www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
    sudo find $path_to_www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
    sudo chown www-data:www-data -R $path_to_www

Comment: I should add more info here. The main issue that started my problems is when I was trying to solve 503 errors. I went into nginx.conf and php5-fpm-www-1.sock files and adjusted some settings as root. the vm now freezes on reboot. I have to power it down. when it starts it does not load all the processes. I can tell by the cpu usage which is near zero while the other two vms are around 15%. new relic says the server is unreachable. this is a high volume site, right now it is running on two VMs and doing ok yet certain things are not running since the down server is the master.

Comment: is there a way to pm someone on this site?

Comment: So this was not a permissions issue. It appears to have been an issue with only chrome. It eventually has resolved itself. Both DNS settings and nginx configs including both domains with and without www. So the settings were correct. I can only conclude that the issue was lying with the browser, given that firefox always worked without issue.